# why $pushAll deprecated but $pullAll not?

Tags: mongodb

mongodb document said that $pushAll is `Deprecated since version 2.4: Use the $push operator with $each instead.`

so I changed all occur of {$pushAll:data} to {$push: {$each:$data}}

It's a boring work!

Do I need to replace {$pullAll: data} to {$pull: {$each:$data}}, then no need to do that in the future ?

Or $pullAll will not deprecated in near future?

Comment: If someone would have a time machine to tell this, they could potentially use it for better things than to find what will be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The usages are actually a little different, so "immediate future" deprecation does not seem to make a lot of sense. The [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) modifier sort of unifies API and is not only for usage with [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) but is also for use with [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/), so there is that reason.

In either of those operations you are not so much "querying" the data, but specifying objects to insert. These could just be scalar values or they could be complete sub-documents to be added to an array.

Let's consider an array in a document:

```js
{ "list": [ 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5] })
```

So aside from [**`$pullAll`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) there is the [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator that actually takes a query as an argument. That means that a [**`$pullAll`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) operation is really just shorthand for this:

```js
db.test.update({},{ "$pull": { "list": { "$in": [ 1,2,5 ] } } })
```

Worth noting here that the "shorthand" notation of [**`$pullAll`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) here only works for scalar values, where as the query document form using [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) can actually remove sub-document forms that [**`$pullAll`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) cannot. Considering this:

```js
{ "list": [{ "name": "fred", "age": 20 },{ "name": "barney", "age": 20 }] }
```

You could not remove all `"age": 20` elements by using [**`$pullAll`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) and would instead need the query form of [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/), not to mention that specifying whole documents as arguments with an [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) would probably not be what you wanted anyway:

```js
db.test.update({},{ "$pull": { "list": {  "age": 20 } } })
```

Also worth noting that some may have expected [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) in there, but since we are querying elements of the array the usage is pretty much implied by being a "query document" applied to the array elements.

So the general response about deprecation, I don't think so as the usage cases are different and there is no need to "unify" with the actions of another operator as was the case for [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/).

Still if you are really that worried about it, I would say the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) form as shown above will still be around for some time.